# JQuery-mobile, Phonegap, iOS, fixed header jumps after leaving input form

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using Phonegap with JQuery-mobile, Phonegap on iOS. I encounter this problem with header jump to the middle when leaving form input.

I already set data-hide-during-focus="true" on both fixed header and footer. This problem is killing me.

Answer (score 3):

If we have only one header bar then we can follow the code only for the main-headerbar.

```
    $(document).on('focus', 'select, input, textarea', function () {
        $('#main-headerbar').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0px' });
    });
    $(document).on('blur', 'select, input, textarea', function () {
        $('#main-headerbar').css({ 'position': 'fixed' });
    });
```

If we have two header bars and Second-headerbar will be shown underneath the Main-headerbar (If main-headerbar’s height is ’47px’ then set top style for the second-headerbar, top : 47px).

```
$(document).on('focus', 'select, input, textarea', function () {
    $('#main-headerbar').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0px' });
    $('#Second-headerbar').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top' : '0px' });
});
$(document).on('blur', 'select, input, textarea', function () {
    $('#main-headerbar').css({ 'position': 'fixed' });
    $('#Second-headerbar').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '47px' });
});
```

OR follow  [iOS fix for position fixed elements on input](http://dansajin.com/2012/12/07/fix-position-fixed/)

Comment: I think my problem is caused because I have form inside an scrollable div, and the div is position absolute. I tried change the div to position fixed, it seem the jump effect is less, but the footer still got scrolled up when I press next/previous.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, and I have the same setup user2412555 used.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similiar problem i was using 1.0.1 and the major issue was arising in of header jumps was in older 2.3 version of android and even in Google Nexus phone. I have searched internet for more and more than after some R&D i realize it was basically mistake of css Below what i have done to solve it

1. Give your header class “.header” of each page
2. Create css class with following code
3. `.header{ border: 0px; position: fixed; width: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 21; }`

Besides if you are facing any issues where the header jumps down after changing the page then add this code
`$.mobile.silentScroll(0);` in `$("#yournextpageid").live("pageshow", function() { $.mobile.silentScroll(0); }`

What Jquery `data-position="fixed"` does is it dynamically adds top position to its header and it has overhead and proves to be very sticky in some devices. Besides it jumps in certain devices on opening the keyboard. Adding above CSS will solve your problems.

Answer (score -1):

in Config.xml change the line    to false it will solve your problem..

Comment: Please be specific. What line you have change?

Comment: I gave you a down vote because you answer didn't refer to the line to change